# npm run build cannot find index.html in public subfolder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I continue to get the error below when I try to build a production version of my app. Npm run build is looking for my index.html file in public, but it thinks my public folder is in my root directory whereas it is in the client subfolder.

`Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: C:\Users\wharfchillin\wharf-chillin-app\public`

My public folder is located in a sub-folder of my app:

`client
--->public
------>index.html`

I have tried to make this clear in my server.js file in numerous ways:
***UPDATED***

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const path = require('path');

const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const plaid = require("./routes/api/plaid");

const app = express();
const publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname);

// Bodyparser middleware
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.use('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(publicPath));
});

// production mode
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') 
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(publicPath)));  

console.log('test')
console.log(publicPath)
```

Any advice would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Is it because of the `=` sign in `path.join(__dirname = 'client/build/index.html')`? You can also console log out `__dirname` to verify where node is running from. Additionally would be nice if you can supply a sample project to test with.

Comment: I made some updates to server.js after the Answer I received below and removed that line of code and still have the same issue (see updated server.js in post). A very similar sample project is this: [link]https://github.com/rishipr/mern-plaid. Currently how you run that project is you use npm run dev which is defined in package.json as `"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""`. There's a second package.json in the client subfolder exactly as mine. If you could get this project to build successfully, I am confident I would be able to implement the same solution.

Comment: Also I tried using console log statements and I can get the publicPath to be set to the correct file location where index.html is (and i've tried setting it to the exact path even), however I'm still getting the issue that during the build index.html can't be found. Which makes me think whatever I'm trying with the publicPath isn't really solving my issue.

Comment: what version of react-scripts are you using? try update it

Comment: I'm running the latest version and that's correctly reflected in package.json (6.13.4)

Answer (score 0):

You are using window os, window os's path use backward slash, but in your node app, you are define the path using forward slash, node has api to handle this, [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths). Stop using path.join

Comment: Hi there. I made those edits but I still receive the same error unfortunately. Index.html still cannot be found. This sample project is very similar to my project structure if this helps: [link]https://github.com/rishipr/mern-plaid. Currently how you run that project is you use npm run dev which is defined in package.json as `"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""`. There's a second package.json in the client subfolder exactly as mine. If you could get this project to build successfully, I am confident I would be able to implement the same solution.

Comment: could you update the question with the updated code you mention above? also did run npm build to build a index.html?

Comment: So I was able to get a build created by including the following in my package.json: ```"build": "cd client && react-scripts build",```. Unfortunately, my objective in getting the build working was to be able to deploy on Heroku. When I push this build to Heroku I get an error stating that there is an "Invalid Host Header".... one more thing I'll try to work through!